# Select Text Created By TextRenderer.DrawText

Tags: c#

I created text using TextRenderer.DrawText(). I want to select that text and rotate and skew for it. Can u give the step? please...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this with TextRenderer, but the functions in there can be somewhat re written using the [Graphics Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx)'s methods. The difference is you can apply transforms to it.